# Simple 3 way delta hedge

Tags: hedging, delta-hedging

Consider 3 futures contracts:

```
A BTC/ETH, settled in BTC 

B USD/ETH, settled in ETH

C USD/BTC, settled in BTC
```

As the markets aren't efficient, sometimes these contracts might move apart from each other.

To calculate the spread, I believe the formula would be

```
spread % = A / (B/C - 1) * 100%
```

If the spread is positive, and you want to earn the spread, which contracts should be long & short?

(I believe it should be long A, short B, long C)

Comment: Typically with this kind of arrangement, any potential arbitrage you see when you assume execution at mid prices vanishes when you consider bid/offers on the underlyings. What it tells you in reality is thst the mid prices are not the midpoint of the bid/offers.

Comment: I agree that you should work with $A_{BID},A_{ASK},B_{BID},B_{ASK},C_{BID},C_{ASK}$ rather than just three prices. Also this is called Triangular Arbitrage,not Delta Hedge.